# Error using split() with curly braces "{"

Tags: java, android, regex, split

There is an issue using `split()` with **curly braces**

```
 String[] values = str_bj.split("{");
```

i need to split string with **`{`** but it throws an error at runtime .......

Error::

```
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.obj/com.obj.ObjectDemoActivity}: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL near index 2:
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802): /{
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):   ^
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802): Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL near index 2:
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802): /{
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):   ^
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at com.ibm.icu4jni.regex.NativeRegEx.open(Native Method)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Pattern.java:383)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:341)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:358)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2044)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at com.obj.ObjectDemoActivity.onCreate(ObjectDemoActivity.java:21)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-23 16:01:30.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6802):     ... 11 more
```

It seems to work OK with other characters, but not `{`

Comment: split expect param is regexp. `{` is service symbol in regex. Use `"\\{"`

Comment: You have to escape the symbol with \  try "\{"

Comment: Om nom nom delicious API documentation...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`{` is used to represent intervals in regular expression, you need to escape it, since `String.split` does use regular expressions.

Use `str_bj.split("\\{");` or `str_bj.split("[{]");`

Comment: True. Same with splitting a string between periods (.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Sample.

```
String str = "YourString{YourString{YourString";
String[] temp;
String delimiter = "\\{";
SepString= str.split(delimiter);
  /* print test */
for(int i =0; i < SepString.length ; i++)
System.out.println(SepString[i]);
```